# Traceroute not working as root, but work on other users

Tags: networking, traceroute

Traceroute is working on all users, but when running as root, everything is ’ * * * ’

```
# As root user
[root]# /usr/bin/traceroute 1.1.1.1 -I
traceroute to 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  one.one.one.one (1.1.1.1)  2.436 ms  2.433 ms  2.417 ms

# Switch to non-root user
[root]# su sam

# As non-root user
[sam]$ /usr/bin/traceroute 1.1.1.1 -I
traceroute to 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  169.254.100.0 (169.254.100.0)  1.291 ms  1.250 ms  1.243 ms
 2  13.106.232.74 (13.106.232.74)  3.202 ms  3.188 ms  3.420 ms
 3  172.70.160.4 (172.70.160.4)  6.058 ms  6.053 ms  6.035 ms
 4  one.one.one.one (1.1.1.1)  2.437 ms  2.434 ms  2.431 ms
[sam]$
```

```
Environment:
RockyLinux 9.2 (Blue Onyx)
kernel 5.14.0-284.18.1.el9_2.x86_64
traceroute-2.1.0-16.el9.src.rpm
Azure VM (Official Rocky image - clean install)
```

I've seen for firewall or privileges non-root users can't perform traceroutes, but what is happening today is a nice-versa!

Here are some investigations, based on below comments:

1. Iptables:

```
[root]# iptables-save -c
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.8 (nf_tables) on Sun Oct  8 13:33:21 2023
*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [8239:955658]
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -d 168.63.129.16/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
[6259:1742375] -A OUTPUT -d 168.63.129.16/32 -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner 0 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -d 168.63.129.16/32 -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID,NEW -j DROP
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Oct  8 13:33:21 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.8 (nf_tables) on Sun Oct  8 13:33:21 2023
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Oct  8 13:33:21 2023
```

2. getcap

```
# As root user
[root]# /sbin/getcap $(readlink -e /usr/bin/traceroute)
/usr/bin/traceroute cap_net_admin=ep
# Switch to non-root user
[root]# su sam
# As non-root user
[sam]$ /sbin/getcap $(readlink -e /usr/bin/traceroute)
/usr/bin/traceroute cap_net_admin=ep
[sam]$
```

3. IP rule

```
# ip rule
0:  from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

4. NFT ruleset

```
# nft list ruleset
table ip security {
    chain OUTPUT {
        type filter hook output priority 150; policy accept;
        ip daddr 168.63.129.16 tcp dport 53 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        meta l4proto tcp ip daddr 168.63.129.16 skuid 0 counter packets 6159 bytes 1716902 accept
        meta l4proto tcp ip daddr 168.63.129.16 ct state invalid,new counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
    }
}
table ip filter {
}
```

5. SELinux

```
# sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled
```

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Are the root and non-root users finding different traceroute programs to invoke?  Often the `$PATH` environment variable can be different between the root user and other users.

Comment: @SottoVoce Nope, they are using the same binary '/usr/bin/traceroute'

Comment: Please provide any specific setting that could alter the outcome depending on the user: `iptables-save -c`, `nft list ruleset` , `ip rule` if there are more than 3 rules, with additional routing tables referenced (`ip route show table ...`). There might be other settings (eg: cgroups, but they should be seen in the firewall rules. There's still eBPF left but that's a start).

Comment: Ah just in case: `ls -lL /usr/bin/traceroute` and `/sbin/getcap $(readlink -e /usr/bin/traceroute)` , as well as (still as root) `id` and `id sam`.

Comment: And specific environment setup (in case someone knows something specific about it, I wouldn't). Example: is this on Azure (guessing from the Microsoft IP address)? Is the VM having some router role? etc

Comment: As you say firewall rules can prevent traceroute working for non-root users. It is also possible (but it basically has to be intentional) to make rules that break traceroute for root,

Comment: Alas you used `iptables -nvL` which gets an incomplete result, instead of `iptables-save -c` I provided (nor `nftables list ruleset`). And didn't mention the result of `ip rule`

Comment: @A.B Thanks, The original post is updated with the requested information.

Comment: While there is indeed a rule about user root (`-m owner --uid-owner 0` from the rarely used iptables security table), but as it's an accept rule towards an unrelated address that's not the problem. This still suggests that some additional mechanism, perhaps SELinux, is in place. I don't have any other idea about this. There are also other possibilities (cgroups with eBPF ...) that could be possible.

Comment: @A.B SELinux is disabled, I Investigated further on Ubuntu 22, and there is no problem for root or non-root users, but on Centos Steam 9 there's a problem with both root and non-root users (result is the same with Rocky 9.2 traceroute for root user)

Comment: TCPdump in both conditions: https://pastebin.com/3viVyBc8
any idea?